# PascalCase in asp.net core for only one version of the API

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi, pascalcasing

I'm currently developing a web API in asp.net core 1.0+. The API is using versioning, so I have a version 1 and a version 2, where the first version is to support an old android application. The problem is that I want to return the JSON of version 1 in PascalCase and the version 2 as camelCase, how to achieve that?

I know you can put this in your startup file, but I don't want it to be global for all API Versions.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
}
```

Example on how I use version on my api:

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Route("v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
...
}
```

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that you can decorate it with the following.

```
[JsonProperty("Name")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then the returned value for name will be PascalCase

Comment: Yes, that's a solution, but not viable and not a general solution :( You can start to move forward based on this: https://codeopinion.com/asp-net-core-mvc-json-output-camelcase-pascalcase/